# Convert Python numeric list to numpy array of float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a list of numbers that need to be converted to floats in an 45 x 45 array.

```
gauss_matrix = [list of 2025 float numbers]
mat_template = np.zeros([45, 45])
for rows in np.arange(45):
    for columns in np.arange(45):
          mat_template[rows, columns] = float(gauss_matrix[np.arange(2025)])
```

Does this start at row 0, loop through columns 0-44. Then start at row 2, loop through columns 0-44 and so on?

Resolved Code: (thanks for the help!)

```
   with open('gaussfilter.csv', 'r+') as gauss:  # Let's me read and write gaussfilter.csv

GaussFilterData = gauss.readlines()  # Reads the lines of the csv file
# print("GaussFilterData: \n", GaussFilterData)

GaussList = []  # Empty list which will be used to append values to from the csv file
# print("GaussList 1: \n", GaussMatrix)

for lines in GaussFilterData:  # Loops through each row of data in gaussfilter.csv
    # print("lines: \n", lines)
    for row in np.arange(45):  # Looping through each row and splitting up the list by commas, while converting each value to a float and not a string
        GaussList.append(float(lines.split(',')[row]))  # Appending each row to GaussList

# print("\nGaussList 2: \n", GaussList)

# Making the array of values from GaussList
gauss = np.zeros([45, 45])  # Matrix of zeros, the zeros are placeholders for the values in GaussList
# print("gauss: \n", gauss)

Counter = -1  # Counter has to start at -1 so that it begins at 0 when referring to row 0 and column 0
for rows in np.arange(45):  # Loop through rows 0 - 44
        for columns in np.arange(45):  # As we are looping through row 0, loop through all 45 columns
            Counter = Counter + 1  # Counter keeps track of the number of cells in the matrix (2025)
            gauss[rows][columns] = GaussList[Counter]

     print("gauss array: \n", gauss)
```

Comment: Have you tried it out? You could print it and see.

Comment: You can just write `arr = np.array(list)` or `arr = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5])`

Comment: How about `arr = np.array(lst)`? Please don't name variables after classes.

Comment: Are you confusing 1D with 2D indexing on `np.array/np.ndarray`?

Comment: @smci The `np.array` function returns an ndarray, so your comment reads rather confusingly.

Comment: You didn't show the code for MatrixTemplate, it's not a standard package, what is it?

Comment: OK this is good to know. But how would I do it for a 2D array?

Comment: @miradulo: yes my mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: @smci It is edited. Matrix Template is literally just an array of zeros that act as placeholders for the values in the list

Comment: NEMM2020: **show the code for MatrixTemplate** already, otherwise this is not reproducible code and there's no point asking us what it does

Comment: `np.array` produces a `ndarray` class object, regardless of whether it is 1d, 2d, higher. @smci

Comment: @smci I edited the post to include the MatrixTemplate = np.zeros([45, 45]) line of code

Comment: @hpaulj: yes, but np.array explicitly declares a 1D array which uses 1D indexing, as per the OP's previous edit of their question... this is a moving target...

Comment: NEMM2020: strong Python convention is only use MixedCase for class names, that's why it looked like there were missing classes. Hence your objects would be named matrix_template, gauss_mat, or whatever. I edited the names for you.

Comment: Thank you all for offering your help, but I am still struggling how to convert this list to an array.

Comment: **Your code is very hard to read and has indentation errors.** Please fix that and edit to follow the universal Python convention of lower_case for all objects and variables, MixedCase for classes. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed very soon.

Answer (score 3):

What about setting the `dtype` of your `GaussMatrix` to `np.float64`?

```
GaussMatrix = np.array(GaussMatrix, dtype=np.float)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: I updated my answer. I expected your GaussMatrix to be a numpy-array. This should work for nested python-lists too. It keeps the shape of the original object, so no reshaping is needed.

Answer (score 3):

First please do not use 'list'.Therefore, I changed it to my_list.

You may make an array using 'np.array()' and You can specify your data type using the optional 'dtype' flag.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
>>> my_array = np.array(my_list,dtype=" ")
```

And always you can check your data type by using:

```
>>> my_array.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: you can use my_array.reshape(n,m)